# Is attack range independent of character height?

Tags: jade-empire

I'm now playing Jade Empire(pretty old game, I know, but looks great). I wanted to use the "strong" character(Tiger Shen), but his plait(pigtail) thoroughly annoys me - that was a symbol of obedience and slavery of Han people under the oppression of Qing dynasty, and I don't like it.

Therefore, my question is, if I choose another character and customize him with the White Demon style, would his attack range still be the same? It looks dubious because obviously Tiger Shen is the tallest of all, and the White Demon style employs kicking... by legs.

Comment: Hi, Anon.  I've retagged your question, and focused your question a little.  We don't allow questions asking about mod recommendations, so I've removed that part as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I've explicitly tried this out, but I've played through the game with several characters (including *Tiger Shen* and the significantly shorter *Radiant Jen Zi* and *Scholar Ling*) and noticed no significant difference between the reach or general effectiveness of the White Demon style.

In case you start with another character, and really want to focus on the White Demon style, please keep in mind that only *Tiger Shen* starts with it as one of his default styles.

He is also the only default character that has character type *Strong*, which means he starts with a high *Body* score, but this doesn't factor into damage (as far as I know).

If that's all not an issue for you then I see no problems in you playing another character.

(Also, I did not see how old this question was before I started writing an answer... I hope you didn't drop the game because of this question!)